# how to access feed items of leads

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

how to access feed items of lead, account, contact and opportunity. here is my code.

```
let path: String =  "/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q2800000SSa7oEAD/feeds"
let request = SFRestRequest(method: SFRestMethod.GET , path: path, queryParams: nil)
SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(request, delegate: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let path: String =  "/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Lead/\(self.objectID)/feeds"
            let request = SFRestRequest(method: SFRestMethod.GET , path: path, queryParams: nil)
            SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(request, delegate: self)
```

Comment: Is this an answer, or did you have the same question?